# Failed to deploy XPS with docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose

The following error shows up when trying to deploy xps with docker compose:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint awesome_ride (f906dc56e1b78a6fbc2fc982e78a1a68643a6b224804508b1e2c569768c5c2cd): Bind for 0.0.0.0:4369 failed: port is already allocated.
```

Commands used to deploy xps:

```
npm run create-compose-file develop
docker-compose -p xavo -f docker-compose.gcr.yml -f compose-files/docker-compose.gcr.develop.yml up -d
```

Answer (score 0):

Check ports currently in use with the following command (CMD with admin):

```
netstat -ab
```

PORT 4369: Erlang makes use of a Port Mapper Daemon (epmd) for resolution of node names in a cluster. Nodes must be able to reach each other and the port mapper daemon for clustering to work.

Solution: Uninstall local installation of RabbitMQ/Erlang OTP.